# C Passing a list from struct to another function

Tags: c, list, struct, pass-by-reference

Can anybody explain me what is happening?
This code works ok:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct def_List List;

struct def_List {
    int x;
    int y;
    List *next;
};

typedef struct def_Figures {
    List *one;
    List *two;
} Figures;

void another_function(List *l) {
    l = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    l->x = 1;
    l->next = NULL;
}

void function(Figures *figures) {
    another_function(figures->one);
}

int main() {
    Figures ms;
    function(&ms);
    printf("%d",ms.one->x);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints "1".
I add third list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct def_List List;

struct def_List {
    int x;
    int y;
    List *next;
};

typedef struct def_Figures {
    List *one;
    List *two;
    List *three;
} Figures;

void another_function(List *l) {
    l = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    l->x = 1;
    l->next = NULL;
}

void function(Figures *figures) {
    another_function(figures->one);
}

int main() {
    Figures ms;
    function(&ms);
    printf("%d",ms.one->x); // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Prints "-1992206527".

It works well with one or two lists, but when I add third or more, something is going wrong. Why?

Comment: Both are **undefined behavior**. `l = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));` do not update caller side variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to modify the argument of `another_function(List *l)`:

```
l = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
```

Use a pointer to pointer instead:

```
void another_function(List **l) {
    *l = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    ...
void function(Figures *figures) {
    another_function(&figures->one);
}
```

Be careful:

```
Figures ms;
function(&ms);
```

While the Figures struct ms is now allocated, Lists one, two and three are NULL and not pointing anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. I thought that after passing another_function(figures->one), where figures->one is a pointer to a list, it could be updated inside another function.